# Primefaces 4.0 - Paginated Data Table Filtering issues

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I built a Relatively simple DataTable and tried to use the filter feature with also using the pagination feature.

in reference to the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf) i created a column for each field in my `Customer` class.

this is my "Controller" Bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named

public class CustomerListController implements Serializable{

     public static final long serialVersionUID = //UID;

     private List<Customer> filteredCustomers;

     private List<Customer> allCustomers;

     public CustomerListController(){
         //some Class that generates a list of sufficiently many 
         //dummy customers on instantiation
         this.allCustomers = new CustomerListProducer().getCustomers();
     }

     public List<Customer> getFilteredCustomers{
         return this.filteredCustomers;
     }

     public void setFilteredCustomers(List<Customers> list){
         this.filteredCustomers = list;
     }

     public List<Customer> getAllCustomers(){
         return this.allCustomers;
     }
}
```

i use following dataTable to render this:

```
<p:dataTable paginator="true" rows="18" scrollRows="15" scrollable="true" 
   scrollHeight="500" var="customer" value="#{customerListController.allCustomers}" 
   scrollable="true" id="customerTable" 
   filteredValue="#{customerListController.filteredCustomers}" widgetVar="table">

   <f:facet name="header">
      <p:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
        <h:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="table.filter()" />
      </p:outputPanel>
   </f:facet>

   <p:Column id="nameColumn" filterBy="name" sortBy="name"
      headerText="Customer" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
   </p:Column>

   <!-- Some more columns in the exactly same 
    manner as this changes only in Customer attribute-->

</p:dataTable>
```

When i press any Key in any given filter field the Table loses all rows and even upon clearing the fields does not display any.

When refreshing the page i get the expected amount of rows & pages.

I will try to provide amendments as requested.

*EDIT:*

I am using Primefaces version 4.0.0 as installed with maven.
I have been digging into console under FF and found the following:
The response XML is empty save the node Entry for updated table. There are no JavaScript errors thrown and the viewstate id sent with the "table data" changes with every keystroke.

Comment: I do not understand how it shows the filtered data even after refresh the page. The `filterBy` attribute must recieve the field `name` of an customer. See page 135 from primefaces user guide. Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Yes my friend @Vogel612.

Comment: Whats your primefaces version?

Comment: It explains the way to do it, i think they made some updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filterBy and sortBy must contain a deferred EL expression.

```
<p:Column id="nameColumn" filterBy="#{customer.name}" sortBy="#{customer.name}"
  headerText="Customer" filterMatchMode="contains">
  <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
</p:Column>
```

**UPDATE:**
Since I could confirm that both EL and non EL approach works in PF V4.0, here is another possible answer to your problem:

Please check your SessionScoped import.

I could not make it work using the javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped.
Using javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped it worked.

Personally I avoid as much as possible the usage of SessionScoped scope, try to use the ConversationScoped instead. It will make a better usage of your server resources.

Comment: on what do you base this??? if i may Quote the user guide for v 4.0:
"Defining *sortBy* attribute enables ajax based sorting on that particular column. [...] sortBy="model" headerText="Model" " (see Page 140) the equivalent sentence and example for filterBy can be found on page 142.

Comment: I just looked at my code. But the version I use is 3.4.2. I´ll check with 4.0.

Comment: I have just updated the PF in my project to 4.0 and it worked seamlessly... can you try this approach and see if it works?

Comment: alright. as i am already half an hour overdue to finish and the deployment may take a while i will try tomorrow if you don't mind... but seeing that two people suggested this approach i guess it might be at least a good start, and at best the perfect solution ;)

Comment: I can confirm that using the non EL approach also works in V4.0. So the root cause of your problem is somewhere else. I will try to reproduce your behavior and submit another answer.

Comment: alright I got it to work with both approaches, just needed to experiment a little after changing the import ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with

```
public CustomerListController(){
     //some Class that generates a list of sufficiently many 
     //dummy customers on instantiation
     this.allCustomers = new CustomerListProducer().getCustomers();
     this.setFilteredCustomers(this.getAllCustomers());
 }
```

No value is provide to the filterAttribute therefore you see a blank dataTable when you do filter.

Hope this help's

Comment: sorry but this also did not work. the filter still just returns empty table, and even after clearing the filter field(s) the table remains empty.

Comment: did u made your class as @ManagedBean("some name")

Comment: as you can see in the provided code, the bean is `@Named` and as the table correctly displays rows when not filtered one can safely assume the bean gets injected correctly. I Just checked console and neither on page load nor on filter requesting there are any errors visible

Comment: @BholaVishwakarma he did this, is a session scoped CDI bean.